# Hazelcast: MapLoader documentation gives empty implementation to loadAllKeys

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am implementing hazelcast MapLoader and it works fine for loadAll and load methods.
But, in documentation they have giver person example and it just returns null in loadAllKeys method.

`public Set<Long> loadAllKeys() {
    return null;
}`

Is this implementation correct or do I need to write any logic here to load keys from database.

Answer (score 1):

If you return null you enable completely lazy loading. Every key will then be passed right down to the database to look up key and value at once.

Comment: and if I want to load keys initially in that case?

Comment: Just return a set of keys

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a correct implementation.

From the Hazelcast documentation 3.4 section "Initialization On Startup":

> You can use the MapLoader.loadAllKeys API to pre-populate the in-memory map
>   when the map is first touched/used. If MapLoader.loadAllKeys returns NULL
>   then nothing will be loaded. Your MapLoader.loadAllKeys implementation can 
>   return all or some of the keys. For example, you may select and return only
>   the hot keys. MapLoader.loadAllKeys is the fastest way of pre-populating the
>   map since Hazelcast will optimize the loading process by having each node 
>   loading its owned portion of the entries.